# Word for the act of administering therapy

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm looking for a word describing the act of administering therapy or of giving therapy to someone.

e.g.

> The job of a therapist is to ________

Comment: Do you expect the single word to the be *last* in the sentence, or  is a transitive verb acceptable?  In other words, can the word fit the construction *the job of a therapist is to ____  patients*?

Comment: @Jason Bassford I really don't know, either is fine.

Comment: *Treat*. *Therapy* is just a Greek word for medical treatment.

Comment: to provide therapy to someone, to treat someone, to have someone as a patient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [therapist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/therapist) is

> one specializing in therapy; especially : a person trained in methods of treatment and rehabilitation other than the use of drugs or surgery · a speech *therapist*

Therefore, the job of a therapist is to [**treat**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/treat) patients:

> **4** : to care for or deal with medically or surgically · *treat* a disease

Or, the job of a therapist is to [**rehabilitate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rehabilitate) patients:

> **2 b** : to restore or bring to a condition of health or useful and constructive activity

Answer (score 0):

Therapizing (ther-ah-pie-zing)
The act of administering therapy to someone.
To therapize

TFD gives the verb:

> [therapize](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/therapize)
> to subject a person to psychological therapy: don’t
> therapize your friends

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For what it's worth, that's a usage I'm familiar with. If you add the supporting detail requested, I'll be happy to upvote your answer.

Comment: This answer may seem plausible in the abstract, but this is a word that is only rarely encountered in the wild. Also, according to the definition quoted in the answer itself, it is limited to psychological therapy, while the OP was looking for something more general.

Comment: I have never seen this and even if it is a word, it simply is not used to describe the treatment provided by a therapist.

Comment: @Lambie I'll grant you that it's not in general use, but it does, in fact, describe the treatment provided by a therapist.

Comment: I have spent years in the "therapy community" (around therapists and other mental treatment providers, not as a patient) and it is simply not used.